# How to get validator to fire or grab the correct controls inside validator?

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I have a custom validator that does not seem to be firing when I change the value of the form fields that I want it to work with. It is a cross-field validation confirm password validator so it is just checking that these 2 fields are the same.

Currently I am declaring and using the validator like this:

```
//declare the validator
export class MustMatchValidator{
static mustMatch(controlName: string, matchingControlName: string): ValidatorFn {
    return (c: AbstractControl): {[key: string]: boolean} | null => {
        const control = c!.get(controlName);
        const matchingControl = c!.get(matchingControlName);

        if (control?.value.equals(matchingControl?.value)){
            return {'mustMatch': true};
        }
    
        return null;
    }
}
}

//set the validator on the form group in component code
  registerForm = this.fb.group({
email: new FormControl('', [
  Validators.required,
  Validators.email
]),
password: new FormControl('', [
  Validators.required,
  Validators.minLength(8)
]),
confirmPassword: new FormControl('', [
  Validators.required,
  Validators.minLength(8)
 ])
}, {
Validator: 
  MustMatchValidator.mustMatch(RegisterConstants.PASSWORD_STRING, RegisterConstants.CONFIRM_PASSWORD_STRING)
});

//use the validator in the HTML
           <div class="form-group">
            <label for="confirmPassword" class='login-label'>Confirm Password</label>
            <input formControlName='confirmPassword' placeholder='Confirm Password' class='form-control' type="password"
            [ngClass]="{'is-invalid': registerForm.get('confirmPassword')!.touched && registerForm.get('confirmPassword')!.invalid}">
            <div *ngIf="registerForm.get('confirmPassword')!.touched && registerForm.get('confirmPassword')!.invalid" class="invalid-feedback">
                <div *ngIf="!registerForm!.get('confirmPassword')!.errors!.mustMatch && !registerForm.get('confirmPassword')!.errors!.required">
                    Passwords do not match {{registerForm.get('confirmPassword')!.errors | json}}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

When I do it this way and then debug it seems that the validator only fires when the page is loading after clicking refresh but if I type into the fields it does not fire. So here the div containing "Passwords do not match {{registerForm.get('confirmPassword')!.errors | json}}" never is displayed.

I thought maybe this could be because the validator should be set on the form control in the component code instead of the form group and so I tried changing it to include this in the form group creation:

```
confirmPassword: new FormControl('', [
  Validators.required,
  Validators.minLength(8),
  MustMatchValidator.mustMatch(RegisterConstants.PASSWORD_STRING, RegisterConstants.CONFIRM_PASSWORD_STRING)
 ])
```

And that did cause validator to fire at the expected time but I don't seem to have access to the correct form controls inside of the validator.

The calls to `c!.get(controlName)` and `c!.get(formControlName)` return null and when I try to access the parent by changing it to `c!.parent!.get(controlName)` the parent is null and this causes an error.

So I need to either be able to either:

1. Get the validator to fire correctly when set on the form group
2. Access both form controls when setting the validator on the form control

Thanks in advance for any help.